# Android 4.1 jellybean emulator not opening apps in android studio in windows

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I have installed latest android studio(2.1.2). when iam trying to open jellybean emulator for testing its showing the screen like attached in image.

Emulator opening for marshmallow.....

Please suggest on this.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is your logcat says can post it ??

Comment: did you waited till emulator started completely

Comment: it did not say any thing... i waited for  morethan 2 hours

Comment: I got it.. Just decreased the RAM Memory to 256MB